# The integral form of inner product .

Tags: calculus

I want to know how scientists know that the inner product of f and g equal to integration from $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\ dx.$$

Comment: It's a definition.

Comment: I think there must be a derivation to it.

Answer (score 15):

An inner product on a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$  is a function $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle : V \times V \to \mathbb R$ which satisfies certain axioms, e.g., $\langle v, v\rangle = 0$ iff $v = 0$, $\langle v, v\rangle \geq 0$ for all $v$.

The definition of an inner product on the vector space of let's say continuous functions on $[0,1]$ of

$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x) \ dx$$

works in that it satisfies those axioms.

Now, given that, it turns out we can use the inner product for a very wide range of useful things.

Historically, the definition was probably inspired by analogy with vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, namely

$$\langle (v_1,v_2,...,v_n),(w_1,w_2,...,w_n)\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n v_iw_i$$

Comment: yes , but how this sigma turns to integration form this is my question.

Comment: By analogy with a Riemann sum. Suppose we sample the functions $f$ and $g$ at $1/n, 2/n, ..., (n-1)/n, 1$. Then a draft of our inner product could be

$$R_n(f,g) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(i/n)g(i/n)$$

We had better normalize this for $n$ otherwise it will run away from us

$$S_n(f,g) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(i/n)g(i/n)$$

Now let $n\to\infty$ so we get closer to capturing all of the information in $f$ and $g$. Then $S_n \to \int_0^1 fg$

Comment: sorry, I don't understand you, could you please give me another simple explanation or the complete origion  prove , I'am just  a student, thank you.

Comment: Which part don't you understand: the definition of $R_n$, or $S_n$, or the limit $S_n \to \int fg$?

Comment: I don't understand the Riemann sum.
I don't listen about it before.

Comment: Riemann sums is how we define the Riemann integral, the integrals you have used in your life up to now:
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/indefinite-definite-integrals/definite_integrals/v/riemann-sums-and-integrals

Comment: ok I understand the video but please could you tell me what's meant by that:
By analogy with a Riemann sum. Suppose we sample the functions f and g at 1/n,2/n,...,(n−1)/n,1. Then a draft of our inner product could be
Rn(f,g)=∑i=1nf(i/n)g(i/n)
We had better normalize this for n otherwise it will run away from us
Sn(f,g)=1n∑i=1nf(i/n)g(i/n)
Now let n→∞ so we get closer to capturing all of the information in f and g. Then Sn→∫10fg

Comment: The expression $S_n$ is a Riemann sum. The idea is that as $n$ gets larger and larger, the sum captures more values of the functions $f$ and $g$. In the limit, $S_n$ converges to the integral. The integral then has all the nice inner product properties. The sums $R_n$ and $S_n$ do not.

Comment: ok but , how n tends to infinite and from the relation of Sn=1/n*gima , so when n tends to infinite , Sn tends to zero ?

Comment: No. $S_n$ is a Riemann sum for the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) \ dx$. In the limit as $n\to\infty$, $S_n$ converges to that integral.

Comment: ok,thank you simon for helping me.

Comment: @SimonS why do you need to normalise $R_n$ to $S_n$? And how you do it?

Comment: What if the field is $\mathbb{C}$ instead? Then we won't have the integral satisfy the definition of inner product, correct?

Comment: @information_interchange you can loosen the symmetric property and redefine it with antisymmetric property